# Calling PHP file with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file that takes a array and an integer and returns a string.
I would like to get that string, however, when I log the result to the console, I see an object and don't see my string anywhere inside

```
result = $.ajax({ url: 'myPhpFile.php?firstargument=myArray&secondargument=myInteger' });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: that's because you aren't waiting for the ajax to complete. Use the success/done callback.

Comment: oh i see, but i'm getting a result back each time so i'm assuming its completing?

Comment: Nope. result will always be an object regardless of the outcome. That object is known as the jqXHR.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to next script:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "myPhpFile.php",
   data: { firstargument: myArray, secondargument: myInteger }
})
.done(function(result){
   console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: this worked great, thank you! is there a reason you used get rather than post?